# how to force a input text to be invalid even if its valid (Java script or Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a form that contains name, email and phone. The name and email validation works correctly.
But the phone validation does not work. So I used intelInputPhone Validation.
Now I can valid my phone number but the form still submits with wrong inputs because it's just considering the default validation.
I want to force it to be invalid if intelInputPhone Validation was invalid.
So here's the main question:

> **How can i change the state of validation of a input?**

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to this plugin? https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input

Answer (score 0):

> but the form still submit with wrong inputs because it's just
>   considering the default validation

I think you expect HTML5 Validation behavior with this [intelInputPhone](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) module. That won't work.

You have to handle validation now inside submit function.

Take a look at the snippet.

```js
var phoneInputElement = document.querySelector("#phone");
const phoneInput = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputElement, {
  initialCountry: "us",
});

$("#form").submit(function(event) {
  if (!phoneInput.isValidNumber()) {
    const errorCode = phoneInput.getValidationError();
  
    const errorMessage = (Object.entries(intlTelInputUtils.validationError).find(([key, value]) => value === errorCode) || ["INVALID_CODE",-1])[0]
    $("#phoneError").text(errorMessage)

    event.preventDefault();
    return;
  }



  var values = {};
  $('#form :input').each(function() {
    values[this.name] = $(this).val();
  });
  console.log(values);

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
#phoneError {
  color: red;
}

input, button, div.iti {
 margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.0/js/utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.0/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.0/css/intlTelInput.css">

<form id="form">
  <input required type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter name">
  <input required type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
  <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone">
  <div id="phoneError"></div>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```